# F5 key stuck on laptop even without keyboard

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure

I'm having a weird problem with F5 key.

the system continuously detect F5 key press. If I open web browser,tabs keeps refreshing.Detect keypress even while booting from external USB device(live linux)

This is what I've done,

- Tried different os - win7 win8 ubuntu
- tried removing keyboard
- RAM test - all clear

Still problem not solved.

laptop details:hp g6-2015tx

Comment: Did you actually remove the keyboard from the laptop?

Comment: Yes I removed keyboard from laptop physically.

Comment: That sounds very weird. if the keyboard is removed, then there is no physical device from which the signal could possibly come. So we cannot assume stuck key or something. I don't want to disappoint you, but if all data you provided is correct, then it sounds like MB problem. Maybe something with keyboard controller or with keyboard connector.

Comment: Everything I said is true I have made video of it I can upload it if you want evidence.

Comment: I did not mean to doubt it. I only meant that there is always room for human error. Double check if your keyboard connector is clean (I assume it is ZIF connector). Give it a gentle brush. That is all that comes to my mind.

Comment: If the laptops freaking out under two different systems with keyboard disconnected, it must be something on the MB.

Comment: Do you mean MB=Motherboard ? BTW I've done all basic diagnostics i.e. cleaning, re-plugging, etc.

Comment: Yes, I did mean motherboard

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an external keyboard? As this may clear any cache the system has and also  would confirm it's a mother board issue. The Keyboard may not work 1st time as the drivers will be installing so plug it in give it 5-10 mins then restart the machine (just to be safe) and try the external.

I had a similar issue with a cursor/touchpad on a laptop and this seemed to resolve the issue.

Sorry I can't comment on this as I don't have enough cred yet :(

Hope this helps :)